# Issue with populating table with foreign key in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm facing a problem populating a table with a foreign key in my ASP.NET Core web application. Strangely, the code works perfectly for a table without a foreign key. During debugging, after clicking the create button, I get a SQL `SELECT` statement for the `Client` table. However, when I click back to the list, I get an `INNER JOIN` statement between `Masina` and `Client`.

Model class:

```
namespace ServiceAuto.Models
{
    public class Masina
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int MasinaId { get; set; }

        // Navigation property
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        public string Marca { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace ServiceAuto.Controllers
{
    public class MasinasController : Controller
    {
        // ... (other actions)

        // GET: Masinas/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["ClientId"] = new SelectList(_context.Client, "ClientId", "Nume");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Masinas/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("MasinaId,ClientId,Marca,Model")] Masina masina)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Masina.Add(masina);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // <-- This line could be the source of the issue
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(masina);
        }

        // ... (other actions)
    }
}
```

Create view:

```
@model ServiceAuto.Models.Masina

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<!-- ... (other HTML) -->

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ClientId" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="ClientId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ClientId"></select>
</div>

<!-- ... (other HTML) -->
```

I've meticulously reviewed every file, and everything seems to be correct. I've ensured that the migration is applied to the database, and there are no error messages. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is caused by you (ab)using an EF entity class as an ASP.NET MVC two-way ViewModel. Don't do that (it's also opens you up to massive security vulnerabilities because you're letting anyone arbitarily set any data-member of the Entity type - using `[Bind]` like you are in your post is an imperfect solution). You need to define a separate ViewModel for your HTML `<form>`+`[FromForm]` model parameter, then map its members to your Entity which you need to load from your `DbContext` on POST _first_.

Comment: it's not clear what the error is, but a couple of things seem wrong here.  You either aren't showing the whole form, or you haven't included all the fields you are binding to.  The other is that I think you are setting a primary key.  That should be null when creating, so that the database creates the key when it's added.  The join is happening on return view?  That would be normal as the Client is coming from another table.